# Necesito subir una API Rest a un servidor web

Tags: api, rest, webservice

tengo una `API Rest` que utilizo en local y necesito subirla a un servidor web. El problema que tengo es que no se configurarla una vez subida para que se comunique con la base de datos SQL del servidor.

El error que obtengo es este:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://error.hostinger.eu/?. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://hanoi.hol.es' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Es la primera vez que tengo que subir las cosas a un servidor, disculpad mi ignorancia :)

PD: acabo de darme cuenta que la api lleva incorporadas las CORS.

`header("Access-Control-Allow-Orgin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json");`

PD-2: solo por descartar, la direccion para que se conecte a la base de datos debería ser esta `$_server = "mysql.hostinger.es";` ?

Comment: Hola Subte, bienvenid@ a SOes, podrías agregar más detalles por favor?

Comment: El error que obtengo es este: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://error.hostinger.eu/?. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://hanoi.hol.es' is therefore not allowed access.` Es la primera vez que tengo que subir las cosas a un servidor, disculpad mi ignorancia :)

Comment: Te esta diciendo que agregues el encabezado acces control allow origin lo puedes hacer en php o apache usando .httaccess

Comment: Sí, eso se ve en las configuraciones del mySQL, verifica que el usuario y password sean los mismos del servidor y que tengan los permisos necesarios. Saludos

Comment: No hay ningún cambio de momento

Comment: @Subte lo pudiste solventar?

Answer (score 2):

Conociendo que estás usando `Hostinger`, es un entorno `LAMP` *(aunque sigo pensando que debería llamarse GLAMP, la G de GNU)* bueno, regresando a la respuesta:

En el root de tu website (donde esta el public_html) hay un archivo llamado `.htaccess` a dicho archivo, agrega la siguiente linea:

```
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Sigue con todo el power al desarrollo! y recuerda, nadie ha nacido sabiendo, todos aprendemos y si es en equipo, mejor :D

Comment: Gracias a todos por la ayuda. He metido el `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` en .htaccess pero no hay ninguna diferencia. Si me pudierais indicar como meterlo en el PHP de la api ya que soy estudiante y mi conocimiento sobre PHP es minimo.

Comment: De nada, sigues con el mismo error o ahora te sale algo diferente?

Answer (score 2):

Este error es muy común, para realizar peticiones a un servicio `Api Rest/Ful`, se debe dar primero permisos a los dominios/host donde serán consumido la `Api`.

Puedes dar permiso a solo uno o los dominios que quieras

**Ejemplo:**

```
('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://misitio1.com');
('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://otrositio.com');
('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.tusitio2.com');
('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.ejemplo.com');
```

Puedes usar el comodín `*` para referirte a todos.

Más información en Mozilla: [Access_control_CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Es decir tu servidor cuando recibe la petición comprueba el `host` de donde lo estás pidiendo y si se encuentra en su lista de host permitidos, te envía los datos.

**Usando PHP**

Establece la siguiente cabecera en todos los recursos que devuelve alguna petición.

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

**Usando Apache en .htaccess**

Establece la siguiente directiva en el archivo `.htaccess` de tu servidor.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

normalmente cuando trabajas una API en local con un motor de base de datos SQL le especificas la dirección a la cuál debe apuntar la API, que en local es localhost o 127.0.0.1, que vienen siendo lo mismo. Ahora, cuando tu aplicación esté en el servidor debes especificarle la dirección de tu servidor más el puerto, por ejemplo: : Lo que está en los signos < (menor que) y > (mayor que) deben ser cambiados por los datos de tu servidor y eliminar estos signos.

Cabe aclarar que los datos de autenticación pueden variar, así que te recomiendo revisar el usuario y la contraseña de la base de datos del servidor para que los cambies también en tu API.

Si obtienes esl siguiente error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://error.hostinger.eu/?. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://hanoi.hol.es' is therefore not allowed access`

es porque incumples esta esta política [Política del mismo orígen] (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica_del_mismo_origen) que especifica que un servidor no puede aceptar peticiones de un dominio diferente. Hay dos formas de solucionar eso: desde el cliente con JSONP o con CORS desde el servidor, donde la más recomendada es usar CORS, porque si lo haces con JSONP cada cliente debería implementarlo, en cambio si lo haces desde el servidor sólo lo haces una vez. Para tu caso específico busca la mejor forma de agregar CORS, por ejemplo si es JAVA busca: "add cors to java web application" o si es para nodeJS con Express puedes buscar: "add CORS to express" y así sucesivamente, de acuerdo al framework que utilices

Comment: El error que obtengo es este: 

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://error.hostinger.eu/?. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://hanoi.hol.es' is therefore not allowed access.`

Es la primera vez que tengo que subir las cosas a un servidor, disculpad mi ignorancia :)

Comment: Vale, editaré la respuesta para darte mayor amplitud con respecto a eso.

Comment: Cristian solucionaate? Quue me interesa tener solución a este .problema también!